# Flip CIImage Horizontal

Tags: ios, objective-c, ciimage

I am trying to flip my CIImage Horizontal with :

```
image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];
image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, sourceExtent.size.height)];
```

But i always get the image flip vertical instead

Comment: why don't you try this   UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgV.image.CGImage
                                                    scale:imgV.image.scale
                                              orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this way:

```
image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, sourceExtent.size.height)];
```

Comment: You meant to the second line to be:
image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(sourceExtent.size.width,0)];

Answer (score 7):

This will properly flip the image horizontally and maintain proper coordinates.

In Obj-C:

```
image = [image imageByApplyingCGOrientation: kCGImagePropertyOrientationUpMirrored];
```

In Swift:

```
image = image.oriented(.upMirrored)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/2919727-oriented

If what you want is to orient it in such a way that you can use it in an UIImage, then you want to flip it in both axes.

```
image = image.oriented(.downMirrored)
```

Comment: I get the error message "'oriented' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer"

Comment: image.oriented(.upMirrored) only works for iOS 11+, how can I implement it under iOS 11?

Answer (score 2):

Alex almost had it, but you need to adjust the translation as well:

```
image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(sourceExtent.size.width, 0)];
```

Answer (score 1):

This what worked for me:

```
UIImage(ciImage: ciImage.oriented(.upMirrored).oriented(.left))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to flip a UIImage (or CIImage) in either horizontal or vertical directions:

```
UIImage *image;
BOOL mirrorX, mirrorY;


CIImage *ciimage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
ciimage = [ciimage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(mirrorX?-1:1, mirrorY?-1:1)];
ciimage = [ciimage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(mirrorX?image.size.width:0, mirrorY?image.size.height:0)];
image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciimage];
```